# software that lists all the css selectors of a stylesheet

Tags: html, css, selector

The title is self explanatory, I'm searching for a software that is well crafted for css writing sheets. I could google it out but I don't doubt on the quality of the replies here, and want some views based on your experience.

Oddant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStorm, Paid but nothing can beat it.

Comment: thanks I've been downloading it's a good software

Answer (score 1):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/

Firefox addon, shows you all selectors used in a site even though the blurb says it's used for finding unused selectors (which is also good if you have bloated css)